# reflexive, symmetric, antisymmetric, transitive

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let B be the set of all strings of 0’s and 1’s. A binary relation G is defined on B as follows: for
all s, t ∈ B, s G t ⇔ the number of 0’s in s is greater than the number of 0’s in t. Determine
whether G is reflexive, symmetric, antisymmetric, transitive, or none of them. Justify your answer

Not reflexive: s > s is not true.

Not symmetric: s > t then t > s is not true

Transitive: for all s,t,a in B, if s > t and t > u and s > u .... I am not sure what i'm supposed to define u as.

Antisymmetric: For al s,t in B, if sGt and tGs then S=t.... s > t and t > s based on definition on B this not true so there s not equal to t. Therefore not antisymmetric??

Help wanted

Comment: For transitivity the claim should read: If $s>t$ and $t>u$ **then** $s>u$. Also, why do you keep using $>$ when the relation is called $G$ in the problem statement? - Also review the antisymmetry part

Comment: becasue based on the definition the number of 0’s in s is greater than the number of 0’s in t.. so isn't it suppose to be the > greater than sign

Comment: and how would i know what U if it's not in the definition?

Comment: for antisymmetric. I'm not sure.. The first condition sGt is true but tGs is false so i concluded since both conditions are not met then it cant be that s = t. so not antisymmetric